# Significant performance penalties when using more than 6 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, amazon-web-services

I am doing a simple coin flipping experiment for class that involves flipping a certain number of coins on a certain number of threads. To run our performance tests for speedup, we use a fixed number of coinflips (I've been using a billion) and change the number of threads. We use AWS extra High CPU instances with 8 cores to run these tests. For some reason, as soon as I use more than 6 threads, I get significant slowdown. Worse than that, it is inconsistent. Sometimes I will get 14 seconds, sometime 2 for the same number of threads and flips. It makes no sense. I have tried using different JVM's (OpenJRE and Sun JVM) and trying a new instance. Below is my code and the benchmark results (in ms). I would love some help. Thanks.

EDIT: So it seems that I solved it, thanks in big part to the suggestions of yadab and Bruno Reis. They suggested using a local variable to keep track of the number of heads, which I think could have been a factor. They also suggested running all my tests from within the same JVM session, which almost definitely was a factor. Thank you for your help everyone.

```
Speedup:
Threads | Flips | Time
1       1000000000  16402 16399  16404
2       1000000000  8218  8216   8217
3       1000000000  5493  5483   5492
4       1000000000  4125  4127   4140
5       1000000000  3306  3304   3311
6       1000000000  2758  2766   2756
7       1000000000  8346  7874   10617
8       1000000000  14370 14414  17831
9       1000000000  14956  14764  15316
10      1000000000  13595 14491  14031
11      1000000000  12642 11188   10625
12      1000000000  10620 10629  10876
13      1000000000  8422  9950   9756
14      1000000000  9284  9546   10194
15      1000000000  8524  4134   8046
16      1000000000  6915  6361   7275
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CoinFlip implements Runnable {
    private final long iterations; //iterations is the number of times the program will run, numHeads is the number of heads counted
    private long numHeads;
    public CoinFlip(long iterations) {
        this.iterations = iterations;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        numHeads = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            if (rand.nextBoolean()) { //True represents heads, false represents a tails
                numHeads++;
            }
        }
    }

    public long getHeads() { //numHeads getter
        return numHeads;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long numIterations , itersPerThread; //iterations: number of iterations, threads: number of threads to run on, itersPerThread: how many iterations each thread is responsible for
        final int threads;
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java CoinFlip #threads #iterations");
            return;
        }
        try {
            threads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            numIterations = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java CoinFlip #threads #iterations");
            System.out.println("Invalid arguments");
            return;
        }
        itersPerThread = numIterations / ((long)threads); //Might cause rounding errors, but we were told to ignore that
        Thread[] threadList = new Thread[threads]; //List of running threads so we can join() them later
        CoinFlip[] flipList = new CoinFlip[threads]; //List of our runnables so that we can collect the number of heads later
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) { //create each runnable
            flipList[i] = new CoinFlip(itersPerThread);
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); //start time
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) { //create and start each thread
            threadList[i] = new Thread(flipList[i]);
            threadList[i].start();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) { //wait for all threads to finish
            try {
                threadList[i].join();
                System.out.println("Collected thread " + i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted");
                return;
            }
        }
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time; //total running time
        long totHeads = 0; 
        for (CoinFlip t : flipList) { //Collect number of heads from each CoinFlip object
            totHeads += t.getHeads();
        }

        //Print results
        System.out.println(totHeads + " heads in " + (numIterations / threads)
                * threads + " coin tosses on " + threads + " threads");
        System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + time + "ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: How many cores on the test system?

Comment: How much memory did you set for your application (-Xmx)?

Comment: There are 8 cores on the test system ( edited to say that). I didn't set an amount of memory, I just used whatever the default was, which should probably be enough since we are not doing anything with memory, just computation in the form of rand.nextBoolean.

Comment: What CPU model exactly are they using? If they are quad-cores with intel HT, it might be the cause of the slow-down.

Comment: I am using amazon EC2, which means that there is really no way of knowing what the hardware is, however, copying directly from the amazon page, what I know I have is "High-CPU Extra Large Instance 7 GB of memory, 20 EC2 Compute Units (8 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each), 1690 GB of local instance storage, 64-bit platform"

Comment: Instead of running the main multiple times, just write a function which takes numberOfthreadStart, increaseByNumber and iteration as input and iterate for multiple time to get expected result. Running main multiple times may not give you actual thread performance.

Comment: False sharing?  Maybe you should add a suitable cache-line-size filler at the start of your CoinFlip data members.

Comment: Martin, or he could operate on a local variable, and save the result in the field 'numHeads' only at the end of the run() method.

Comment: @BrunoReis - true.  There is not exactly a huge amount of 'data members', so your approach is probably easier, so I added a comment vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Java tests that run in a short amount of time (less than 30 seconds) are just not suitable for performance testing.  The hotspot compiler and other java runtime mechanisms are optimizing your code during the the first large number of seconds your application is running.  Your timing deviations can easily be attributed to JVM startup, optimizations, and shutdown.

If you want a more realistic timing then you are going to have to run for 30 or so seconds and *then* start your timing run.  Also, I would recommend that you multiply the test runs by at least an order of magnitude to better average out the affects of OS overhead, GC, background tasks, etc..  So warm up your application letting it run for 30 seconds, start your testing and the timer, let it run for at least a minute, stop the timer and record your results, and then shutdown the JVM.

Also, it makes more sense to graph how many coin flips you do in a certain amount of time then to see how long it takes to do a certain number of coin flips.  The difference is that you want all of the tests to be running for the same amount of time if you can.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you're only executing CPU-bound operations, there is litte sense in using more threads than available cores. In contrary, the usage of additional threads increases the overhead of context switching and scheduling.

Comment: The thing is, these machines are supposed to have 8 cores, so it should run well on up to 8 threads, and I feel like there shouldn't be that dramatic of a decrease in performance...

Comment: 1) Are you running on a 'cold' JVM? Or have you started benchmarking after some cycles of execution without restarting?
2) Are there any other active processes running on the machine?

Comment: PartlyCloudy: 1) Yes, for each trial, a new JVM was started with java CoinFlip whatever whatever, so each JVM should be running on it's own 2) There is nothing running on the system, except for whatever the default ubuntu system installs. Nothing heavy though.

Comment: It is 8 virtual cores, so it is 4 real cores and 4 via hyper threading (or what it is called by AMD).

Answer (score 3):

If you are running a VM the available cores can also be virtual.  Sometimes you might be getting 8 different cores, and sometimes you might be getting 4 cores x 2 threads each.

I suspect the underlying machine has 6 cores with 2 threads each, of which you can use up to 8.

Answer (score 2):

Your threads are CPU-intensive, it is, they don't block waiting for some slow resource to be ready, so threads compete with each other for CPU.

I bet that each thread get paused in order to put other fellow thread on execution. It is, the execution time-slices are always exhausted. So there is a lot of context switching between threads with no real gain comparing it against only 6-threads (assuming six threads can be executed simultanously).

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance on your source shows no bottlenecks (no fine-grained synchronization anywhere).

In the comments you mention that you are running on a cloud service. Most likely that is a virtualized system that also performs services for other clients.
If that assumption is true, you can not expect to perform any meaningful benchmarking, since you have no idea what other processing the system might perform aside your own workload.

Try your test on a local workstation, it should exhibit much less variation - but naturally there will still be some variation (there are no guarantees that each thread will receive an equal slice of CPU).

Answer (score 0):

The number of threads should not be greater than the number of CPU cores that you have. You will get penalized because the VM would have to switch the threads be